# Laravel Validation Errors in Blade: Multiple Forms Showing Same Messages

Tags: laravel

In my view I have multiple forms. When I receive a validation error on one form, it displays the validation error message on all forms. How can I update this so the validation error will only be displayed on the form that caused the validation error? Thank you.

View:

```
<form method="post" action="/post/comment/{{ $post->alt_id }}" class="form-inline">
    <input type="text" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('comment') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" id="comment" name="comment" placeholder="Add a comment...">
    @if ($errors->has('comment'))
        <p class="invalid-feedback">{{ $errors->first('comment') }}</p>
    @endif
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ Session::token() }}"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 5):

You may use [named error bags](https://laravel.com/docs/master/validation#named-error-bags):

```php
return redirect('previous_page')
            ->withErrors($validator, 'first_form');
```

You may then access the named error bag in your blade from the `$errors` variable:

```php
{{ $errors->first_form->first('comment') }}
```

If you're using Laravel >= 6.10, the `validateWithBag` method may help you:

```php
$request->validateWithBag('first_form', [
    'title' => ['required', 'unique:posts', 'max:255'],
    'comment' => ['required'],
]);
```

Using the [@error](https://laravel.com/docs/master/validation#quick-displaying-the-validation-errors) directive, the 1st arg is an attribute and 2nd arg is the named bag:

```
<input
    id="comment"
    type="text"
    class="@error('comment', 'first_form') is-invalid @enderror"
>

@error('comment', 'first_form')
    <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ $message }}</div>
@enderror
```

Comment: In my view, do I need to name the form in order for the validation to know which form it is validating? Such as, name="first_form".

Comment: @MattPierce no just modify your controller to name error bags and modify `$errors` variable on each form to get/show its relevant errors.

Comment: how can we add is-invalid class?
like in normal cases we add like class="@error('name') is-invalid @enderror"

Comment: @JunaidMasood I updated my answer. please don't forget to give a score if you find this answer useful.